is there a way to dynamically add tasks to asyncio tasks or to AnyIO TaskGroup?
I am new to asyncio, threading and Message Brokers and I am struggling with non-blocking execution. I will explain a bit more about the solution I wrote and appreciate any suggestion on how to improve it.
Also this is my first question, so do not hesitate to ask for clarification or teach me the culture
My application was created to consume messages from the Broker queues which represent tasks, that should be run. The result of the task and generated logs should be pushed to another Broker queues.
Message consumers are running in threads. All the messages they consume goes to shared queue.
Tasks are executed in the Runtime class. Runtime get tasks from the shared queue, build parameters that should be passed to the task and execute it. When the queue is empty it sleeps for some time to wait for the tasks.
This code starts application:
async def start():
    shared_queue = Queue()
    futures = []

    for kind, actor in ACTORS_MAP.items():
        logger.info("starting")
        event_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        listen_thread = Thread(target=run_loop, args=(event_loop,))
        listen_thread.start()

        futures.append(
            asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(
                ainit_and_listen(kind, shared_queue), event_loop
            )
        )
        # await asyncio.sleep(1)

    runtime = Runtime(shared_queue)
    await runtime.invoke()

This is code for listening:
async def ainit_and_listen(actor_kind: str, runtime_queue: Queue):
    logger.info("Declaring queue for {0}".format(actor_kind))
    connection = await connect(os.environ.get("RABBIT_URL"))
        
    channel = await connection.channel()
    
    exchange = await channel.declare_exchange(os.environ.get("CONSUMER_EXCHANGE"), "topic")
    
    queue = await channel.declare_queue(f"{os.environ.get('TEAM_ID')}.{actor_kind}")
    await queue.bind(exchange=exchange, routing_key=f"{os.environ.get('TEAM_ID')}.{actor_kind}")
    
    logger.info("Queue was declared and binded for {0}".format(actor_kind))
    
    await listen(broker_queue=queue, runtime_queue=runtime_queue)
    await asyncio.Future()

async def listen(broker_queue, runtime_queue: Queue):
    while True:
        logger.info("Listen to {0} queue".format(broker_queue.name))
        incoming_message: Optional[
            AbstractIncomingMessage
        ] = await broker_queue.get(timeout=1, fail=False)

        if incoming_message:
            # Confirm message
            await incoming_message.ack()
            data = json.loads(incoming_message.body)
            runtime_queue.put(data)
            
            logger.info("New message of {0} kind".format(data["actor"]))
            
        else:
            logger.info("No new messages. Sleeping...")
            await asyncio.sleep(os.environ.get("CONSUME_FREQUENCY"))

Runtime class main methods:
    async def invoke(self):
        await self._init_pub_exchange()
        just_logger.info("Producer exchange was successfully declared")

        await self.run()

    async def run(self):
        self._running = True
        just_logger.info("Run starts")
        async with anyio.create_task_group() as tg:
            while True:
                await self.process_queue(tg)

    async def process_queue(self, task_group):
        while self._queue:
            data = self._queue.get()
            just_logger.info("Processing next message")
            task_group.start_soon(self.process_node, data)
        
    
    async def process_node(self, data):
        user : User = User.model_validate_json(data["user"])
        workflow_id = data["workflow_id"]
        actor = data["actor"]
        arguments = data["arguments"]
        
        schema = ACTOR_SCHEMAS[actor['actor']]
        
        actor_obj = self.init_actor(actor, workflow_id)
        just_logger.debug("Initialized {0}".format(actor['actor']))
        
        actor_params: dict[str, Any] = self.get_messages(schema, arguments)
        actor_params["context"] = self.build_context(user)
        actor_params["tools"] = self.build_tools(user)
        just_logger.debug("Set up {0}".format(actor['actor']))
        
        actor_coro = actor_obj(**actor_params)
        
        try:
            just_logger.info("Executing {0}...".format(actor['actor']))
            results: list[BaseMessage] | BaseMessage = await actor_coro  # type: ignore

        except TypeError as e:
            just_logger.error(
                "{0} Actor run finished with error:\n{1}".format(actor["actor"], e)
            )
            raise TypeError(
                f"Exception while running the {actor['actor']} actor: {e}"
            ).with_traceback(e.__traceback__)
        
        just_logger.info("Finished {0}".format(actor['actor']))

        if isinstance(results, list):
            json_results = [result.model_dump_json() for result in results]
        else:
            json_results = [results.model_dump_json()]

        await self.publish_result(workflow_id, actor['node_id'], json_results)
        just_logger.debug("Published {0}").format(actor['actor_id'])

I want to be able to start the task at the moment I get them in the queue and do not wait for the result in the Runtime.
I considered to use AnyIO task group and pass a callback as the parameter, but it does not start executing.
is there a way to dynamically add tasks to asyncio tasks or to AnyIO TaskGroup?
I want to see this output:
>>> New message 1
>>> New message 2
>>> New message 3
>>> New message 4

>>> Set Up 1
>>> Executing 1

>>> Set Up 2
>>> Executing 2

>>> Set Up 3
>>> Executing 3

>>> Set Up 4
>>> Executing 4

>>> Finished 1
>>> Finished 2
>>> Finished 3
>>> Finished 4

And this is what I get:
>>> New message 1
>>> New message 2
>>> New message 3
>>> New message 4

>>> Set Up 1
>>> Executing 1
>>> Finished 1

>>> Set Up 2
>>> Executing 2
>>> Finished 2

>>> Set Up 3
>>> Executing 3
>>> Finished 3

>>> Set Up 4
>>> Executing 4
>>> Finished 4


Please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - your question. while complete, requries one to wade over more than 100 LoC  - with lots of details that are irrelevant to your problem.

That said, picking an item from the queue and creating a task with it with a tg.start_soon  call seems to be the right thing to do. Now there is a lot of code around to figure out why is not that behaving as you want it to.

As far as I can tell by looking at this code, the fault might be in the unssen code for actor_obj : unless it yields to the async loop (by using await statements itself), this code is synchronous. You put a lot of code that we don't need - but the core code where the fault may be located is not there.
